# Load previous or next images without reloading page

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, image-gallery

I'm building a simple gallery system using predominantly PHP and MySQL. One of the requirements is for moving to the next image using keyboard arrow keys.

When doing this, the next or previous image should load into the image `div` without reloading the entire page.

The choice of which image to show is based on PHP GET using a URL structure like below, where 273 is the photo ID in the database:

`/photos/photo.php?id=273`

This is the code for housing the image:

```
<div class='single-image-container'>
    <img src='/photos/" . $row["event_id"] . "/" . $row["filename"] . "' />
</div>
```

Is there a straightforward method to load the next image into the div 'single-image-container' when the right arrow key is pressed, by incrementing the value in the GET? The image filenames are in the format of `event_id-id.jpg`, i.e. 1983-101.jpg, 1983-102.jpg and so on.

The goal is also to update the browser URL with the updated id.

I'm a little bit at sea with this one and wondered if someone has some pointers. Thanks.

Comment: Lots of ways, probably easiest to use jQuery to change the img src attribute, like [here](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-change-the-image-source-using-jquery.php).

Comment: Looks good, not sure how to get the next/previous image relative to the one being displayed though.

Comment: You could track the current ID in a JS variable or hit an AJAX target to get a list that you can iterate through.

Comment: Hi, you print all images and then onload of page hide all image expect 1st one . Then using next/previous button show required images

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way (apart from iframe witching). Php is a server-side programming language. If you want new data from the server you have to reload the page first. But no problem, there is javascript. You can load all images directly with php and hide the unnecessary ones with javascript. Then you can build your own control (it's not that hard) or choose one of the hundreds of javascript slider libraries.

If you want to try it yourself, this will help you:
https://www.sitepoint.com/make-a-simple-javascript-slideshow-without-jquery/

But the slider from this tutorial does not support keyboard. But you can use that:  `addEventListener("keydown", event =>`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event

If you want a library. I have used the splide-slider quite often and know that it is easy to use.
https://splidejs.com/

Comment: Can you not combine javascript and PHP? So the javascript gets a request for the next image and it then runs a PHP / MySQL query to check which image to go and fetch and then loads it in? Or do this with jquery? It would be madness to load in all images first, as some albums will contain hundreds of images.

Comment: To better understand your question: Do you want a slider or a lightbox? In a slider hundreds of images would be really difficult to accommodate. But maybe I misunderstood your question and you actually want a gallery with lightbox, so all images on one page and when you click on one it fills the screen. And there you want to navigate with the arrow keys? Generally you can manipulate the `src` of your `<img>` tag with Javascript: [link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_intro_lightbulb) (but please do not use `onclick` you should always use `addeventlistener`)

Comment: No lightbox, and only a slider in so far as on a mobile device swiping the image produces the same effect to load the next image (a la Facebook). On a desktop, no slider effect would be perceptible.

Comment: okay, then try to manipulate the `src` attribute with javascript. Create a javascript array with all links. Maybe it makes sense to render the links in there with PHP if they change. Then you can always change the src. If the images are large, it may not run smoothly. Then you might have to load some images in advance. Good luck!